# process blocked in msgrcv

Tags: linux, process, ipc

I have a process that is blocked in `msgrcv` as shown by `ps -eo pid,tid,wchan`. Is there any way to find the PID of the process that my process is expecting to receive a message from? The communication method used is message queues using the methods provided in `sys/msg.h`.
You can see below the output for `ps`:

`ps -eo pid,tid,wchan,comm | grep Process
 3020  3020 -      ProcessB
 3021  3021 msgrcv ProcessA`